# mdr text is missing for many report numbers

Tags: data-request, api, openfda

I am using the below mentioned adverse event device open API url but it is not giving MDR text for many report numbers like 2112667-2023-03226, 2112667-2023-03227, 2112667-2023-03228 etc though the MDR text is present for same report numbers in https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfmaude/detail.cfm?mdrfoi__id=17224075&pc=BSZ

This is the API which I am using:

[https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=date_received:[20230601+TO+20230629]AND+device.device_report_product_code.exact:%22BSZ%22&limit=1000](https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=date_received:%5B20230601+TO+20230629%5DAND+device.device_report_product_code.exact:%22BSZ%22&limit=1000)

Kindly suggest.

Thanks,
Shailendra J

Comment: Hi Support team, looking forward to hear on this.

Answer (score 0):

I see the issue you're seeing and it looks like some records have empty values for the field mdr_text - we'll open a bug report and investigate. Thank you for bringing this to our attention.

Regards,

Violet Wren

openFDA Tech Lead

Comment: Hi Wren, thanks for your message. Further I look forward to you for the mdr text resolution.

Comment: Hi Wren, any update on this issue?